# Jquery - setting radio button with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a page with "reload" buttons on widget areas.  The widgets contain textareas and radio buttons.  When I click the reload button I'm trying to set the text of the textarea and selection of the radio button.

My current code is working on the first click of the reload button.  The textarea and radio buttons are set properly with test values.

I then type in the textarea and change it's text, and select a different radio button value.  When I click the reload button the textarea and radio buttons should have their test values reloaded.

However, only the textarea's value is being reloaded.  The radio button's selection doesn't go back to the test selection.  Why is this only working the first time I click the reload button?

Here's my code:

```
$('.refreshTextandRadio').click(function () {
    var itemName_Text = $(this).attr('reloadName_Text');
    var itemName_Radio = $(this).attr('reloadName_Radio');
    var evalID = $(this).attr('evalID');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "JDFormAJAX_Reload.asp",
        data: 'itemName_Text=' + itemName_Text + '&evalID=' + evalID,
        success: function (msg) {
            $("textarea#" + itemName_Text).val(msg);
        }
    })

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "JDFormAJAX_Reload.asp",
        data: 'itemName_Radio=' + itemName_Radio + '&evalID=' + evalID,
        success: function (msg) {
            $('input[name="' + itemName_Radio + '"][value="' + msg + '"]').attr('checked', true);
        }
    })

});
```

The ajaxURL page simply returns test values, not really relevant enough to include here.  Does anyone know why this code sets both values on the first click, but only restores the textarea and not the radiobutton on following clicks?

Comment: Why are you doing two simultaneous Ajax requests to the same URL? And why is that necessary to use an Ajax request to "reset" a form to default values ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For dynamically generated content, you should **attach your event handler to an html element that is not being (re)generated using your Ajax**, and not the element that is being regenerated by Ajax (in your case, your button with class `.refreshTextandRadio`.

So, you should attach your click event to the next higher (parent) element that is not affected by your Ajax. Just for illustration I'll use `document`, which is definitely higher than any of your buttons, and attach your click handler there.

So your original code:

```
$('.refreshTextandRadio').click(function () {
   //your actions
});
```

could be re-written as:

```
$(document).on('click','.refreshTextandRadio',function(){
  //your actions
});
```

Of course, you'll want to use a lower parent element (not affected by Ajax, as discussed above) to make your code more efficient.

Hope this helps!

Comment: +1, this is the right way to do it.  For those interested, this is called "event delegation", and the jQuery team have published a good how to page at https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/